# How does God/Goddess choose their vehicle?

Tags: gods

In Hindu Mythology, Almost every God/Goddess have their vehicle and they are symbolised by that .

for example
Lord Ganesh vehicle is Mouse.
Lord Kartikey vehicle is Peacock.
Lord Yama vehicle is Bull.

So My question is is there any story behind choosing the vehicle by god ?

Comment: Yes, stories r there..for example "Why Lord Ganesha has a mouse as his vehicle" is given [here](http://www.biodiversityofindia.org/index.php?title=Why_Lord_Ganesha_has_a_mouse_as_his_vehicle)...but if u want all stories then it's too broad..I suggest u to limit your question..

Comment: The story of Lord Vishnu choosing Garuda as his Vahana is present in Mahabharata and its possible that some other stories might also be present . Will try to answer your question but we may not find the direct answer of all the gods choosing their Vahanas.

Comment: Related [Why isn't a human the vahana (vehicle) of any God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6657/3500)

Comment: Could it be that humans are the vehicle of all the Gods ? What consciousness feeds grows.